# my app cannot discover mongodb when using docker-compose up, links is not working?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

We are docker-compose up our golang service and mongodb. The service is unable to discover mongodb. I suppose somehow links is not working. Has anyone faced this issue?

AUTH_DB_HOST="mongodb://mongodb:27017"

```
version: '3'

services:

  app:
    build: .
    image: golang:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/go/src/github.com/dickmanben/qube-auth
    working_dir: /go/src/github.com/dickmanben/qube-auth
    command: bash -c "go get ... && go build -o main . && ./main"
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
    links:
        - mongodb
    depends_on:
        - mongodb

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.4.3
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    expose:
        - 27017
```

Comment: Note that the `links` directive is deprecated. You should no longer use it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not expose port in MongoDB service. Try this.

```
version: '3'

services:

  app:
    build: .
    image: golang:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/go/src/github.com/dickmanben/qube-auth
    working_dir: /go/src/github.com/dickmanben/qube-auth
    command: bash -c "go get ... && go build -o main . && ./main"
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
    links:
        - mongodb
    depends_on:
        - mongodb

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.4.3
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
```